# communication with 2 databases with always encryption through procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, always-encrypted

Currently I am working on migration of my DB to SQL server 2016 with always encryption. I have 2 Databases and selecting data from one DB from other table through stored procedures. when selecting or updating the encrypted columns from DB1 by using stored procedure in DB2 I got  Operand type clash: error.
I have created column master key and column for the 2 databases with same name and same certificate.

```
use CustDb1

Select  @custSSN = customer 
        from    CustDb2..customer a
        where   a.SSN = @psSSN
```

SSN column in customer in the both DB are encrypted but when I run this I got the below error:

> Msg 33277, Level 16, State 6, Procedure copy_customer, Line 891 [Batch
>   Start Line 167] Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables
>   '@psSSN'. The encryption scheme for the  columns/variables is
>   (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC',  encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'TestCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'CustDb2')  and the
>   expression near line '940'  expects it to be (encryption_type =
>   'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'TestCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'CustDb1').

Answer (score 0):

Best practices for data migration using Always Encrypted are documented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/01/07/best-practices-for-moving-data-encrypted-with-always-encrypted/). Please follow the directions specified in the blog for data migration.

Currently, cross Database comparisons on encrypted data are not supported by Always encrypted

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nikhil. Its a working product and there are more than 250 procedures that are using this kind of logic. It is very difficult to move all the logic to .net within a short time. is there is any alternative way to handle this in sql server itself?